# Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I wrote a simple project in Java, using default configuration in IntelliJ IDEA. I built the project and ran it successfully. I was using Java 1.9. I wanted to check if it runs with Java 1.8. I changed the JRE in the configuration from Java 1.9 to Java 1.8 and ran my project. The following error occurred:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)
```

This question: [IntelliJ Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034197/intellij-error-a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try) is different because it has `NoClassDefFoundError` instead of `UnsupportedClassVersionError`. This question [A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again in Eclipse x86 Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381202/a-jni-error-has-occurred-please-check-your-installation-and-try-again-in-eclips) is also different because it regards Eclipse, not IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, editing a component configuration in `.idea/misc.xml`. 
It was

```xml
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_9" project-jdk-name="9.0" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
  <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/out" />
</component>
```

and I changed it into

```xml
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" project-jdk-name="8.0" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
  <output url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/out" />
</component>
```

Then an applet appeared, which helped me add a new JDK (Java8) and I was able to run my project and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is our manifest files doesn't match the project. What I did is solved my problem. I had provided codes for chat client and server.

First I opened a new Java project.then created a package ,and then what I did is created two classes (you can give any name since we change it later.) for my 2 existing classes.

Then I opened existing classes in notepad,copy all the content and paste them to
newly created classes. 
An error occurs saying

> names doesn't match

. Rename compilation units.
Then `run`..worked for me.

Comment: Do I get it right that you had a total of 2 classes in your application?

Comment: Yes ..service and client

Comment: Your solution might be good for small applications, but rewriting every class in bigger applications (100+ classes) is out of the question.